# With antd custom svg icons, how to pass props down to svg?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, icons, antd

The example at the end of this page is not clear:
[antd custom icon instructions](https://ant.design/components/icon/),
how do I pass the "fill" property to the component when using a custom svg:

```
<Icon component={MessageSvg} />
```

This doesn't work:

```
<Icon component={MessageSvg} fill="red"/>
```

as it doesn't paint the Icon red, but standard gray.
Isn't antd supposed to pass down the props?

but but, If I do this:

```
<MessageSvg fill="red" />
```

then it works.
So in theory I could wrap Icon and do an HOC to solve this, but I am sure I am missing something maybe.

I am using the webpack extension @svgr/webpack

```
 {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
                {
                    loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                    options: {
                        icon: true,
                    },
                },
            ]
        }
```

Comment: How are you creating/importing your `MessageSvg` svg?

Comment: Like this:

import MessageSvg from "../assets/svg/MessageSvg.svg";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found out.

```
<Icon component={() => <MessageSvg fill="green"/>}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following component allows to change icon attributes with css

```js
import SVG from "react-inlinesvg";
import MessageSvg from "./Message.svg";

export const MessageIcon = (props) => (
    <Icon component={(iProps) => <SVG src={MessageSvg} {...iProps}/>} {...props}/>
)
```

### Example of the usage

```js
export const App = () => (
    <MessageIcon className="icon-primary"/>
)
```

Then we can change all properties we need

```css
.icon-primary {
   color: #32E0C4 !important;
   font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

P.S. This method works well with `svg` files downloaded from [iconfont.cn](https://www.iconfont.cn/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as per [the custom-icon demo](https://ant.design/components/icon/#components-icon-demo-custom) you'll have to pass the fill style as props like you did

`<MessageSvg fill="red">`

change it to

`<Icon component={MessageSvg} style={{color: "red", fill: "red"}}>`

Also notice how they use the fill="currentColor" in the actual svg component.
Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't work. What it does is to just set a style for the enclosing Icon tag, but that doesn't affect the fill and other properties on the svg tag. There must be a way to pass these attributes on from Icon otherwise what's the point of exposing them in the documentation if we can't manipulated them.